# В WebApp(telegram) при запросе выдаёт 403

Tags: telegram, fastapi, web-apps

При выполнение запросов из браузера подобной ошибки нету.

Она проявляется при передачи jwt tokena, выдаёт 403 Forbidden {“detail”: “Not authenticated”}, при это на backend(Fastapi) даже нигде не выводится такая ошибка

Comment: Ничего не понятно. При передачи откуда? Передачи как? При чём тут fastapi? Приведите [mcve] наверное?